# Why am I getting an error when trying to compile 32-bit code with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile a file as x86 but I keep getting this error: `(Main.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86')`

I set up my build task accordingly as such:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "CL",
            "args": [
                "/D WIN32",
                "${file}",
                "\"C:\\Users\\Axair\\Desktop\\VScode\\OpenGL\\GLFW\\lib-vc2022\\glfw3.lib\"", // 32 bit library
                "/link",
                "/MACHINE:X86"
            ],
            "presentation": {
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": true,
                "close": false
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Console output looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Axair\Desktop\VScode\OpenGL>cl /D WIN32 "C:\Users\Axair\Desktop\VScode\OpenGL\Main.cpp" "C:\Users\Axair\Desktop\VScode\OpenGL\GLFW\lib-vc2022\glfw3.lib" /link /MACHINE:X86
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.32.31332 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.32.31332.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:Main.exe
/MACHINE:X86
Main.obj
C:\Users\Axair\Desktop\VScode\OpenGL\GLFW\lib-vc2022\glfw3.lib
Main.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
```

The compiler keeps recognizing Main.obj as an x64 module despite the specified WIN32 option.

Comment: I thought about that so I changed my path to `C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.30.30705/bin/Hostx64/x86/cl.exe` and the console still shows that I'm using the x64 version of the compiler. I also tried to set up the environment variables by launching vsvars32.bat and I checked with the visual studio installer if I had the 32-bit build tools and saw that they come as a bundle. @fabian

Comment: since you have a visual studio installed ,I suggest building a project inside of VS with high level of "build output verbosity" (which can be found in menu>>options>>projects and soultions>>build and run). That can give you lots of info on the build process.

Comment: x86 or x64 is not set by means of compiler flags but by choosing the right cl.exe. For x86 you need the `...\x86\cl.exe` one, for x64 the `...\x64\cl.exe` one. The `...` is basically something like `C:\Program Files\...\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin`. The `Hostx64` or `Hostx86` should work the same; they just define the instruction set of the compiler itself, not of the produced executable. So VSCode selects the wrong compiler. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc): You need to start VSCode from the appropriate command prompt, or perform extra setup.

Comment: My bad, the path I specified in my first comment was the right one but had nothing to do with the build task. I removed the 64-bit path variable and added the one for 32-bit and everything compiles! Not very clean but it works, thanks. @Sedenion

Answer (score 0):

The compiler version was set to x64. I changed my PATH variable to point to the right version of the compiler, in my case -> `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\Hostx64\x86`

Comment: Usually you are supposed to load a bat file or start a developer command prompt to set all environment variables correctly. Compare [here at the bottom](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2022). Just changing the path to the cl.exe without all the rest that the bat files are doing might lead to problems down the line.

Comment: I used to do it that way and I get the same error now, that was driving me mad then. I even tried copy-pasting the task code from the doc, but the console shows that it doesn't recognize 'C:/Program'  as an internal or external command. I put the path between quotes as such `"\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat\""`. I've looked everywhere for a solution, nothing solved it. @sedenion